# alternatives to Libre Office?

Tags: applications, appcenter, libreoffice

Is there a recommended alternative for Libre Office?

preferably available as a flatpak for elementary OS6?

I have frequent trouble with LibreOffice Calc freezing the whole elementary.
The only way out is to restart the PC.

I have searched interweb and it seems I am not the only one suffering this.

I have tried all suggested remedies/settings with no change ...

It is entirely possible that the culprit is my hardware?

(Yes, I have installed correct drivers for my nvidia GPU)

but I will not be able to change it easily or quickly - I am stuck

so... what alternatives are you using/suggesting? help, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Been using OnlyOffice for quite sometime, give it a try.. it's available in flatpak as well

Comment: Interesting suggestion, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I am trying Apache OpenOffice 4.1.12

https://www.openoffice.org/download/index.html

very good installation instructions and easy to get going

So far it seems OK (hasn't frozen once yet...)

Answer (score 0):

Long term update...

have been using OpenOffice 4.1.13 for a while and it was kind off OK, but spreadsheet started slowing down totally when I tried sorting and filtering large data file,

so... tried going back to Libre Office - unfortunately it started freezing Elementary when using spreadsheet (as previously).

In the OnlyOffice solved the problem - it not only easily copes when sorting and filtering large spreadsheet data file, but also doesn't cause any problems with Elementary.

I recommend OnlyOffice !!! (based on my experience - YMMV)